# How to get the current offset use IDC or IDAPython?

Tags: python, reverse-engineering, ida

When writing an IDA script, how to use IDC or IDAPython to get the offset for a memory address?

Answer (score 0):

```
offset = idaapi.get_fileregion_offset(ea)
ea = idaapi.get_fileregion_ea(offset)
```

Thanks Igor Skochinsky

ref:https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/2835/how-to-extract-the-input-file-offset-of-a-byte-in-idapython